# Send JSON data to MySQL database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I need to send JSON data to a MySQL database, but when I am trying to do this, my code only sends "{"0":"A" to the MySQL database.

Here is my code:

**JavaScript**

```
<span id="start_button_container">Send and start</span>

const allCards = {
    '0':'A &#9830;','1':'A &#9829;','2':'A &#9827;','3':'A &#9824;',
    '4':'10 &#9830;','5':'10 &#9829;','6':'10 &#9827;','7':'10 &#9824;',
    '8':'K &#9830;','9':'K &#9829;','10':'K &#9827;','11':'K &#9824;',
    '12':'Q &#9830;','13':'Q &#9829;','14':'Q &#9827;','15':'Q &#9824;',
    '16':'J &#9830;','17':'J &#9829;','18':'J &#9827;','19':'J &#9824;'
};

let userInTable = localStorage.getItem( 'saved_user' );
if (userInTable) { // Save user and find table onclick START
    saveUser.style.display = 'none';
    hello.textContent = "Hi " + userInTable;
    start.onclick = () => {
        if (userInTable) {
            let x = new XMLHttpRequest();
            let url = "php/findtable.php";
            let data = JSON.stringify(allCards);
            let params = "cards="+data+"&user="+userInTable;
            x.open("POST", url);
            x.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            x.send(params);
            x.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) {
                    console.log(x.responseText);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
if (isset($_POST["cards"],$_POST["user"])) {
    $cards = $_POST["cards"];
    $user = $_POST["user"];
    $query = "INSERT INTO tables (u_1,all_cards) VALUES (?,?)";
    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $cards);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            print_r($cards);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can we see the PHP code which does the saving into the database please?

Comment: P.s. this is a bit of a mess. You're sending data in two formats - url-encoded as the main format but with JSON in the middle. It's better to be consistent. It would probably make more sense for this situation to send the whole payload as JSON.

Comment: @ADyson application/json not helped

Comment: Because of the Space. can you print_r the POST before you insert it.

Comment: @Gurami I didn't say just to change the content- type and nothing else. There would be more to it than that. You have to actually make the whole payload a single JSON object, and you have to alter the PHP to read it as JSON.

Comment: @ADyson could you explain what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encodeURIComponent() function helped me a lot:

```
let data = JSON.stringify(encodeURIComponent(allCards));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you/somebody still want to know *why* this happens, every ampersand (&) is a new input in a querystring. Meaning `var1=value&var2=value&var3=value`. Your JSON contains ampersands, so the parser thinks you are starting a new variable.

```
var1=value&var2={"a":"&2934;"}
                      ^ This one starts a new variable
```

var2 contains `{"a":"1` and processes `2934;"}` as a new variable name.

`encodeURIComponent` escapes the ampersands, so the query string parser does not use it for division of variables.